# Integral of Forces is the Velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces

I am self learning classical mechanics.  I have the following problem:  At time $t$ we have a force $f(t)$ acting on a particle with mass $m$ that is at distance $x(t)$ from $0$.  We also assume $x(0)=x'(0)=0$.  The text says to prove that
$$
x'(h)=\int_0^h f(t) \, dt.
$$
I feel it should say $mx'(h)$.  Here is my reasoning:  By Newton's Law, we have that $f(t)=mx''(t)$.  So, 
$$
\int_0^h f(t)\, dt = \int_0^h mx''(t)\, dt=mx'(h)-mx'(0)=mx'(h).
$$
Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, in order to have the correct units, you need to have a factor of mass in there.

Comment: However, the term f could have units folded into it, you have to see how it is defined

Comment: By the way, you need to specify what the integral is with respect to. Here, integral of force with respect to t is momentum.

Comment: Usually mathematical physics books tend to ignore physical quantities like mass, that could be the reason